# How and where to rename msapp-error.html file to error.html?

Tags: uwp

I am building a UWP Hosted Web application. When the app encounters a network error, it redirects to a file msapp-error.html. I would like to have it renamed to error.html. Where should I make changes in order for the UWP app to redirect to error.html rather than msapp-error.html? I am posting this because it is unclear from the Microsoft Documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How and where to rename msapp-error.html file to error.html?

`msapp-error.html` file will be loaded automatically in the iframe when errors occur due source resources not loading or not found! and this internal page and we could not rename it. But you could edit their style or add some tag. Please note `"httpStatus", "failureName", "failureUrl"` were used by `msapp-error.js`, please avoid remove it.